# storeUpload MongoDB and PHP

Tags: mongodb, php

If I use the storeUpload method, the data are well stored in the DB. My problem, is about the server response, the Nginx throws a "502 Bad gateway" (and the storeUpload method does not return the id).

There is a SIGSEGV error in the php-fpm log file.

Any idea ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
cd /tmp
git clone https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver
cd mongo-php-driver/
phpize
./configure
make
make install
service php5-fpm restart
```

... DONE

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PHP-343